# SQL - Loop through duplicates to make new conditional column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sooooo I have data in Oracle database, from which I take some rows that looks like this

```
ID  TYPE 
1   A
1   B
2   A
```

I have a list of Types that translate to conditional column, like (if A then Y, if B then N), so it looks like this

```
ID  TYPE COND
1   A    Y
1   B    N
2   A    Y
```

Is there a way to add another column, that would check if all values in COND column for specific ID are Y? So final result would like this:

```
ID  TYPE COND COND2
1   A    Y    N
1   B    N    N
2   A    Y    Y
```

I know I could easly do this in R, but skipping using other software in this process would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an analytic function.  In this case `min()` does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       min(cond) over (partition by id) as cond2
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table x101;
create table x101 (
id intEGER,
typ varchar2(20)
);


insert into x101 values (1, 'A');
insert into x101 values (1, 'B');
insert into x101 values (2, 'A');
insert into x101 values (4, 'A');
insert into x101 values (4, 'C');
insert into x101 values (5, 'A');
insert into x101 values (5, 'T');
commit;

With q1 as (
select id, typ,
       case typ 
          when 'A' then 'Y' 
          when 'B' then 'N' 
          when 'C' then 'Y' 
          else 'NA' 
       end as cond
from x101
order by id, typ
)
select id, typ,
       cond,
       case 
          when count(distinct case when cond != 'Y' then 1 end) over (partition by id) = 0 then 'Y' 
          when count(distinct case when cond != 'Y' then 1 end) over (partition by id) = 1 then 'N' 
          else 'NA' 
       end as cond2
from q1
order by id, typ
;
```

gives

```
ID  TYP CODE    CODE2
1   A   Y   N
1   B   N   N
2   A   Y   Y
4   A   Y   Y
4   C   Y   Y
5   A   Y   N
5   T   NA  N
```